# how to change location of swap

Tags: partitioning

I am a new user of ubuntu 20.04. I installed and put swap partition in my laptop's (Dell inspiron 7520) original 30 Gb SSD. My main SSD is 480 Gb, ubuntu is in a 100 Gb partition. I made the WHOLE partition as root (/), so I can't have a /home and a /swap partition in the SAME SSD.
Is it possible to REPARTITION my ubuntu installation so I can have a /home and (if possible) a /swap partition located in the same disk? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you didn't use "something else" during the installation then (1) /home is inside / as folder, not a partition and (2) Ubuntu no longer requires a swap partition, a swapfile is installed by default; even if you had a swap partition already created it wouldn't be used unless doing a manual partitioning installation with "something else".

Comment: I DID use "something else", but I ended up putting my /swap in another SSD.
So, HOW could I delete this swap partition in another SSD so I can use the 30 Gb SSD, and HOW can I shrink the 100 Gb partition I put my ubunto on (in my MAIN SSDE, shared with Windows 7) so I could use a /home partition (it has advantages)?

Comment: Ubuntu will use any swap partition and file it can find, (Type `free` in Terminal). Ubuntu will prefer a swap partition it finds in /etc/fstab. After creating your new swap partition go to fstab and change the existing swap UUID to suit, (or add a second swap line if you want two swap partitions).

Comment: Edit your question and show me `grep -i swap /etc/fstab` and `free -h` and `sudo swapon -s` and `sudo blkid`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.